# didRangeBeacon called without any beacons found

Tags: ios, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I registered my own location manager to monitor and range a few beacons:

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
```

My understanding is, when one or more beacons is found this delegate method is called:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

This delegate method is indeed called when I turned on my beacon, but the beacons array is empty. Is there any reason why my beacon is not listed in that array?

Here's a screenshot to illustrate this situation:

[image]

---

#### Other things to note:

- I used [MacBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/macbeacon/) to transmit my beacon signal. I will try to use a real beacon later, but MacBeacon has been working fine for me in iOS 7.
- I tried delaying ranging until I get `didEnterRegion:` or `didDetermineState:` is called, but that still result in the same thing.
- I have requested location permission from my location manager: `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`.
- I have a very similar code working fine compiled in Xcode 5/iOS 7 SDK. Is this a specific Xcode 6/iOS 8 behaviour?
- I have added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in my plist.

Comment: What desktop operating system version are you using with MacBeacon?

Comment: @davidgyoung I'm using Mavericks, 10.9.4.

Comment: Your note helped me! :) I had to put [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is because I am not using unique identifier when creating `CLBeaconRegion`.

Special thanks to [nayoso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1545363/nayoso) for helping me solve this.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Do you mean what you're passing as the 'identifier' property is not unique in the context of your app, or not an NSUUID object?

Comment: @MickByrne I mean when you create the CLRegion like this: `initWithProximityUUID: identifier:`, make sure that the second argument (identifier) is unique.

Comment: I have the same problem. What you exactly did to make it working? This is how I define my region in Swift: `let myRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "dhajhdjsahdjsahdjkah")`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Do you have any other region with identifier "dhajhdjsahdjsahdjkah"? If you are doing this in a loop, take it out of the loop, or create unique identifiers.

Comment: no, this is the one and only identifier. I think I have a wrong `UUID`, and now they are not default, because they might have changed.

Comment: voted down because u didn't provide full solution instead of thank some one

Comment: @JackKFouani The answer is right there buddy, right before I thanked him.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo i did your solution what do u mean by identifier is uniq ? i can't find the identifier of my beacon they are about 12 beacons

Comment: @JackKFouani It's the identifier you used when creating a CLBeaconRegion object that you used to start monitoring or ranging.

Comment: I am providing correct uuid and correct identifier.still getting beacons count 0 in didRangeBeacons. Did anyone have any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Locate app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) on your iOS 8 device, and verify you see the beacon.  Make sure you have the UUID of the beacon configured into the Locate app properly.

If you do see it on Locate, then I suspect the issue is that permissions are not properly granted to your app on iOS 8.  In this case, you should probably post a code snippet showing your setup where you call `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` and also include a section of your plist file which needs to have something like:

`<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need to use location services</string>`

Comment: Yeah, the beacon is visible from Locate app (and other beacon apps actually). I've also added that in my plist, sorry I forgot to mention it. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you actually get the permissions prompt?  Try uninstalling and reinstalling your aspp to verify.

Comment: Yes, I did, I reinstalled it. I actually took out my code and paste it on a sample project and it's now working. The only difference is I hardcoded the UUID, major, and minor. So I think this may have something to do with my monitoring more than 1 beacon code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I found out the problem. Apparently I can't reuse the identifier in my CLBeaconRegion when creating multiple regions. I needed to create unique identifiers. Thanks a lot David.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The region identifier must be unique or a second region with an identical identifier will replace the first.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first start beacon monitoring also set notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES

```
self.region1.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
[theLocManager startMonitoringForRegion: region1];
[theLocManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion: region1];
```

That code works just fine for me also in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem when I created my CLBeaconRegion with a major and minor as arguments. If you create the beacon region with major and minor arguments and don't have any beacons with those major and minors the beacon list will be empty. In my case, I wanted to dynamically determine the major/minor. Once I init the CLBeaconRegion with just the UUID and Identifier all was well.