# CLLocationManager's delegate function 'didRangeBeacon' doesn't find any beacons?

Tags: ios, swift, beacon, cbperipheral

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429089/didrangebeacon-called-without-any-beacons-found), but it's not solving my problem, I will explain why it doesn't solve the problem at the end of the question.

What I'm doing takes 2 steps:

1. Let CBCentralManager discover peripherals
2. Let CLLocationManager listen to beacons discovered in step 1

I found out the UUID of my beacon with the following delegate method:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral.identifier)
}
```

Then step 2 takes place:

```
if let uuid = UUID.init(uuidString: "<identifier found in step 1>") {
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: .init(proximityUUID: uuid, identifier: UUID().uuidString))
}
```

My locationManager's delegate method simply prints all beacons in range:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print(beacons)
}
```

But all I'm getting is an empty array. Why? How do I fix this?

The question listed above suggests that when creating a `CLBeaconRegion`, we should give a unique identifier, which I am already doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this statement:

> > I found out the UUID of my beacon with the following delegate method:
> >
> > ```
> >  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
> >      print(peripheral.identifier)
> >  }
> > ```

**The value returned by `peripheral.identifier` is not your beacon's `proximityUUID`.**  Because of this, the `didRangeBeacons` returns an empty array, because there are no beacons in the vicinity with a `proxmityUUID` matching the `CLBeaconRegion` you set up.

Here's a deeper explanation:

The `peripheral.identifier` field comes from the `CBPeripheral` object, which inherits it from `CBPeer`.  Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbpeer/1620687-identifier) describes it this way:

> > The value of this property represents the unique identifier of the peer. The first time a local manager encounters a peer, the system assigns the peer a UUID, represented by a new NSUUID object. Peers are identified by NSUUID UUIDs instead of by the CBUUID objects that identify a peripheral’s services, characteristics, and characteristic descriptors.

Basically, this field is just a temporary identifier assigned to bluetooth device by iOS.  While it is represented by a `NSUUID` (as it's called in Objective C or just `UUID` in Swift), and the `CLBeacon`/`CLBeaconRegion` have a `proximityUUID` field that is also an instance of `NSUUID`, **they are not the same value.**  This is a common source of confusion.

Unfortunately, **it is impossible to use CoreBluetooth APIs to get the ProximityUUID of your beacon**.  Apple intentionally goes to some lengths to prevent you from doing this.  Sorry.